# ehcache value need to implement serializable?

Tags: ehcache

For Ehcache, are there any constraints on the **value** that needs to be put in to? Like key does the value also need to implement **'serializable'**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Objects used in Ehcache only need to implement Serializable if you need to store the cache on disk or are using cache replication

So the implementing Serializable for the **values** is optional.

@Louis
As soon as you use a disk tier, objects have to be represented as byte arrays to be stored on disk and in Java the only standard way of doing that is Serialization.
***well said***

Answer (score 12):

Ehcache puts constraints on key and value types at two different levels:

- First one is the API, where `Element.getKey` and `Element.getValue`, both deprecated, return a `Serialiazable`. But there are two alternative methods:

  - `Element.getObjectKey`
  - `Element.getObjectValue`

  which are the recommended ones anyway, and thus there is no restriction in the end.
- Second one is the use of multiple tiers. As soon as you use a disk tier, objects have to be represented as byte arrays to be stored on disk and in Java the only standard way of doing that is `Serialization`.
- Third one is when you want to enable *store by value* semantics, where again, the only standard way of doing a deep copy in Java is through `Serialization`.

That later points are the two cases where your keys and values must implement `Serializable`.